# How can I fix the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'.'

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, forms

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'.'`

I am getting this error whenever I try to click on `List_Patient_Button` on my form.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Patient_File_Form
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlAdp As SqlDataAdapter
    Private Sub Patient_File_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim connStr As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Patient File.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        sqlConn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
        sqlConn.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Patient_File_Form_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub List_Patient_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles List_Patient_Button.Click
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Nom, Prénom FROM file ORDER BY Nom", sqlConn)
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        adapter.Fill(ds, "allFiles")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("allFiles")
        If (dt.Rows.Count = 0) Then
            MsgBox("No patients found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, " No Data")
        Else
            PatientListBox.Items.Clear()

            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                PatientListBox.Items.Add(dr("Nom") & " . " & dr("Prénom"))
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the complete error that I get:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   at WindowsApp1.Patient_File_Form.List_Patient_Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\hp\source\repos\WindowsApp1\Form1.vb:line 22
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at WindowsApp1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 83
```

Comment: Think you'll find file is a reserved word, might need to enclose it in [file] square brackets

Answer (score 2):

`File` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server, so you need to put it between `[]`.

```sql
sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Nom, Prénom FROM [file] ORDER BY Nom", sqlConn)
```